# Cannot configure 'vpcSubnets' without configuring a VPC

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, github, aws-cdk, vpc

I'm currently working on a project at work that should be a platform based on multi accounts for each company.

So basically each account is for each company with their own db and resources.
The issue that has occured from the GitHub pipeline is the VPC LookUp from the other stack. Local synth and deployment, it works perfectly fine but when try to deploy it through the GitHub workflow i always get the following message

> Cannot configure 'vpcSubnets' without configuring a VPC

Just to clarify more.

Stack A - Consist of a VPC network with a Database cluster instance
Stack B - Consist of lambda function for system purpose
Stack C - Can consist of another lambda function

So Stack A is deployed without any errors, VPC and DB Cluster works perfectly fine.
Stack B on the other hand don't work to deploy and get's the message above.

```
const importedVpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, "external-vpc", {
  vpcName: "globalVpc"
});

const systemLambda = new LambdaFunction(this, "SystemLambdaFunction", {
  description: "System Lambda Function",
  functionName: "SystemLambdaFunction",
  entry: "src/lambda/system/index.ts",
  handler: "handler",
  vpc: importedVpc,
});
```

Been trying a variation of different approaches but get's the same output during workflow.
I know on local machine it fetches the data from AWS account and cache them in the cdk.context.json file but seems as it does not work during pipeline

how can i make a lookup work in the pipeline?

Comment: There are a couple of places this could be a problem. In your work flow, if the vpc/ec2s arent finished when StackB goes to ask for the info, None/Null will be returned. So a delay might be needed in your flow/pipeline to wait for it (or some kind of check to make sure it is set up before continuing).

If t hey are all deployed "together" (ie not two `cdk deploy` or can't be deployed separately) then you can expose the VPC as a property on Stack A and pass it into stack B. Be aware this can cause some stack dependencies tho, which can be very annoying to work around.

Comment: I experienced this problem after upgrading from CDK 1.x to 2.x. Still working on a solution 

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was experiencing was that I was illogically specifying a subnet selection on AWS Lambda functions that were outside of a VPC.

Original code:

```js
const myFunction = new lambda.Function(this, name, {
    ...
    vpc: useVpc ? vpc : undefined,
    vpcSubnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT },
});
```

Working code:

```js
const myFunction = new lambda.Function(this, name, {
    ...
    vpc: useVpc ? vpc : undefined,
    vpcSubnets: useVpc ? { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT } : undefined,
});
```